# Using Inkscape, how do I have 2 nodes make a single curve instead of two?

Tags: inkscape

[image: 2 Nodes Making 2 Lines]In Inkscape, these 2 nodes have 2 lines connecting them (though it is one path).  I want the 2 nodes connected by a single line so that I can divide the cross shape into 2 shapes.  How is this done?

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE, Not sure why you'd make a closed path when an open path would have done. Is there some reason you did that? You can use a Division boolean operation with an open path and a closed shape (the X). [see example](https://imgur.com/4mtdOsD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's not quite clear to me what exactly the desired result is. If you just want to make one of the segments a straight line, first make sure 'Show bezier handles of selected nodes' ([image: Icon for 'Show bezier handles']) in the toolbar is enabled, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the round bezier handles on either side of the segment to remove them.

If you actually want to completely remove the segment, then there is the problem that you can't use the 'Delete segment [...]' button ([image: Icon for the 'delete segment' button]) in the toolbar directly, since Inkscape can't tell which one of the segments you want to remove based on which nodes are selected. Instead, double-click the superfluous segment to temporarily add a new node there, select the two new split segments and delete them with the button above, one after the other.

Alternatively, it might be faster to just create a new path with the bezier tool and don't close it this time by right-clicking or pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of clicking the start of the path.

Comment: The second solution is what I was looking for.  I had to create a third node to delete the second segment.  Thank you.